# Linear dependence in End(V)

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand the definitions of linear dependence and independence.
However, if we have a vector space $V$ and a linear operator $f$ (i.e. $ f: V \rightarrow V $ ) and $\dim(V)=n$, that implies the vector space End$(V)$ of endomorphisms had dimension $n^2$. This means that $id, f$,$f^2,..,f^{n^2}$ must be linearly dependent in End$(V)$. Why is that the case?

Comment: There are $n^2+1$ elements in the list you wrote and they live in a vector space of dimension $n^2$.

Comment: As its name suggests, matrix calculation is calculation, but here it proves useful theoretically since for example if $E=\mathbb R^2$, End$(E)\sim \mathbb R^4$, with clearly indeed dim$(\mathbb R^4)=4$

Comment: a basis of a vector space is a maximally linearly independent subset of $V$, all bases of a vector space have the same cardinality. its cardinality is the dimension of $V$, So any subset of cardinality >$n^{2}=Dim(V)$ must be linearly dependent.

Comment: That clears it up, this might be a silly question but why must $id, f$, $ f^2,...,f^{n^2} $ $\in End(V)$

Comment: If $f,g\in\operatorname{End}(V)$, then if $h=fg$ ($h(x)=f(g(x))$ for all $x\in V$) then $h\in\operatorname{End}(V)$

Comment: As @kabenyuk wrote, $\forall x,y \in E, f^{\circ 2}(x+y):=f(f(x+y))=f(f(x)+f(y))=f(f(x))+f(f(y))=f^{\circ 2}(x)+f^{\circ 2}(y)$ for example : i 'll let you do $f^{\circ 2}(\lambda x)$

Answer (score 0):

Let's do a few reminders:

- $\forall x \in V, f^{\circ 2}(x):=f(f(x)), f^{\circ 3}(x):=f(f^{\circ 2}(x)),...$
- then it is easy to convince oneself that $f^{\circ 2}\in \text{End}(V)$. For example, $\forall x,y \in V, f^{\circ 2}(x+y):=f(f(x+y))=f(f(x)+f(y))=f(f(x))+f(f(y))=f^{\circ 2}(x)+f^{\circ 2}(y)$
- The same applies to $f^{\circ k}$, for any $k\in \Bbb N^*$
- dim$V$=n; let's take for example $n=2$ and the field $\Bbb R. $ Then we know that there is an isomorphism between End$V$ and $\mathcal M_2(\Bbb R)=\left\{ \begin{bmatrix}a &  b\\c & d\end{bmatrix} :(a,b,c,d)\in \Bbb R^4\right\}\approx \mathbb{R}^4$. From where we get dim$V=n^2=2^2=4$. As soon as we have five elements of End$V$, we are therefore certain that they are linearly dependent.

The previous point applies in particular to $\{id,f,f^{\circ2},f^{\circ3},f^{\circ4}\}$. And as usual everything generalizes to any dimension $n$ and for any field.